# Unable to display image icon in button

Tags: css, html

I have an html file in which I want to display icons in button. 
I am using 3 different images of by **Awesome Font** i.e

```
<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I have included its library in my project.

Only first image tag i.e `<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true">` is working rest are not displaying the icon. Need Help!
Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onUnAssignUsers()"><i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>Unassign Users</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onAssignUsers()"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Assign Users</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onUsers()">Users</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the most recent version of Font Awesome?

Comment: How do you include the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using latest version of Font-Awesome.
Here is the link i used for fiddle and is the latest CDN from [bootstrapcdn](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/).

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

You missed out `<i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>` on `Users` Button.

Check https://jsfiddle.net/luzan/det1ovqa/

Answer (score 1):

you are not using the latest version. Those icons are included in version 4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I think there is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-your-fontawesome-css-file/css/font-awesome.css">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io//assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
     <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onUnAssignUsers()"><i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Unassign Users</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onAssignUsers()"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Assign Users</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="onUsers()"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Users</button>
          </div>
```